# LustyExplorer is not loading

Tags: macvim

I added [lustyExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890) to ~/.vim/plugin.  Then I ran MacVim and tried to run it with ":LustyFileSystemExplorer".  Error

> "Unknown Function: lustyExplorer#LustyFileSystemExplorerStart"

In the documentation it says:

```
Usage:
"                 <Leader>lf  - Opens the filesystem explorer.
"                 <Leader>lr  - Opens the filesystem explorer from the
"                               directory of the current file.
"                 <Leader>lb  - Opens the buffer explorer.
"                 <Leader>lg  - Opens the buffer grep, for searching through
"                               all loaded buffers
"
"               You can also use the commands:
"
"                 ":LustyFilesystemExplorer [optional-path]"
"                 ":LustyFilesystemExplorerFromHere"
"                 ":LustyBufferExplorer"
"                 ":LustyBufferGrep"
```

I also tried `:lf` and got Error:

> can't open errorfile errors.err

Am I executing it correctly?  What does the prefix `<Leader>` mean?

Comment: From the docs: "This plugin requires Vim be compiled with Ruby interpretation." So does MacVim have Ruby support? To check run: `mvim --version | grep -i ruby`

Comment: Yes, I already checked this.

Comment: Dead set on using this? I'm a big fan of [NERDTree](http://vimawesome.com/plugin/the-nerd-tree) for a file explorer and I recommend using [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim) as your plugin install in `*vim`.

Comment: So far I've tried peepopen and lustyexplorer and both of them are broken :).  I'll try NerdTree next I suppose.

Comment: I really recommend using `Vundle` to manage the installs of your plugins.

Comment: @IanC. You are the second person to tell me that :).  A coworker said the same thing.  I'm going to :).

Answer (score 1):

If you have dowloaded the file from github seems to be incorrect. Use the download link in the [plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890) page [lusty-explorer.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=17529) that works as expected